# Contents/MacOS does not exists in 4.5.2

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to upgrade my project from eclipse 3.8.2 to eclipse 4.5.2. While building my project with pde build, I am getting this following error. \Contents\MacOS does not exist.

This part was working fine with earlier version.

I have updated java SDK, delta pack to 4.5.2

Details:

```
C:\p4root\common\build_templates\eclipse_pde\build.xml:144: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec] C:\eclipse4.5.2\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.9.100.v20150521-1524\scripts\productBuild\productBuild.xml:45: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec] C:\eclipse4.5.2\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.9.100.v20150521-1524\scripts\build.xml:129: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec] C:\p4root\myproject\dev\build\myproject\configuration\customTargets.xml:29: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec] C:\eclipse4.5.2\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.9.100.v20150521-1524\scripts\productBuild\allElements.xml:20: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec] C:\eclipse4.5.2\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.9.100.v20150521-1524\scripts\genericTargets.xml:195: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec] C:\p4root\myproject\dev\build\myproject\base\package.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.all.xml:27: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec] C:\p4root\myproject\dev\build\myproject\base\package.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.all.xml:15: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec] C:\eclipse4.5.2\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.9.100.v20150521-1524\scripts\productBuild\allElements.xml:35: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec] C:\p4root\talon\dev\build\myproject\base\package.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.macosx.cocoa.x86_64.xml:92: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec] C:\p4root\myproject\dev\build\myproject\base\package.org.eclipse.pde.build.container.feature.macosx.cocoa.x86_64.xml:1555: C:\p4root\myproject\dev\build\myproject\base\tmp\eclipse\Contents\MacOS does not exist.
```

Any help will be appriciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you finally succeeded to resolve this? I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse 4.5 is packaged as a Mac OS X application. Although the name is displayed as `eclipse` the actual directory name is `eclipse.app`. So you need to change your path to end with `eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Given that the question does not show any of the configuration files being used for the build this is about as much as it was possible to say. You might do better asking a new question showing more information

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with a workaround. I added a `pre.archive` callback to `cusstomAssembly.xml` that move files to right folders:

```
<target name="pre.archive">
    <condition property="is.macosx">
        <equals arg1="${config}" arg2="macosx.cocoa.x86_64"/>
    </condition>

    <!-- Do only for OS X -->
    <antcall target="move.macosx.files" />
</target>

<target name="move.macosx.files" if="is.macosx">
    <copy todir="${eclipse.base}/${launcherName}.app/Contents/MacOS" verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="${eclipse.base}/../MacOS" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${eclipse.base}/${launcherName}.app/Contents/Resources" verbose="true">
        <fileset dir="${eclipse.base}/../Resources" />
    </copy>
    <move file="${eclipse.base}/${launcherName}.ini" todir="${eclipse.base}/${launcherName}.app/Contents/MacOS" verbose="true" />
    <replace file="${eclipse.base}/${launcherName}.app/Contents/MacOS/${launcherName}.ini" token="tmp" value="../.."/>
</target>
```

---

The second workaround is to use Eclipse 4.4 Luna instead of 4.5+. More information on this is here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=468131